# Can there be a vacuous tautological consequence $F\vDash F$?

Tags: logic, definition, propositional-calculus

Can there be a vacuous tautological consequence $F\vDash F$?

Since $α⊨φ \iff ⊨α→φ$ then is: $(k∧¬k)⊨(p∧¬p)$ for example considered a tautological consequence?

Comment: Yes, $p\land \neg p$ is tautological consequence of $k\land \neg k$, more, it's a vacuous tautological consequence.

Comment: Note, however, that it's not of the form $F\models F$.

Comment: @GitGud but both statements are always false.

Comment: Yes, but the LHS of $\models$ must be equal to the RHS. It is not because $p\neq k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is a consequence of the definition of $\models$ between two formulas:

> $\phi \models \psi$ iff $M \models \phi$ implies $M \models \psi$ for all models $M$.

(In the case of propositional logic, the models are the lines of a truth table.) Now since $M \models F$ can never occur, it vacuously follows that $F \models F$, and indeed that $F \models \phi$ for every formula $\phi$.